# ERB is not getting some values of a local hash

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am using Sinatra and rendering views with ERB.
I have the following action

```
get '/user/:id' do
  u = @users.retrieve( params[:id] )
  u[:mykey] = [1,2,3]
  erb( :user, :locals => { :user => u } )
end
```

and the view looks like this

```
<body>
    <h1><%= user["name"] %></h1>

    <pre><%= user["mykey"].to_json %></pre>
```

and where I expect to get the `[1,2,3]` array, I get a big fat `null`.
Primitive values such as the name, are passed without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this of class Hash or HashWithIndifferentAccess?

You are setting `user[:mykey]` and retrieving `user["mykey"]`. Use symbol or string, don't mix them unless you are using HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Comment: yay! that's the ticket. any clue on how to convert a hash to a HashWithIndifferentAccess ?

Comment: I would just make sure to be consistent about the way you're accessing them. You can convert like this, though: `indifferent_hash = hash.with_indifferent_access`. You can also call `symbolize_keys!` on a hash and it will convert all string keys to symbols.